# Method to construct an open rectangle inside an open ball

Tags: general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

I came across this while studying some topology - my school uses the definition of a set $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ being open as there being an open rectangle $R$ for all $x \in U$ such that $x \in R$ and $R \subset U$.

However, from reading any textbook, I see that the definition is normally the same as above, except we look for open balls, so I'm trying to prove that these definitions are equivalent. I managed to construct open balls that contain the point in question given an open rectangle, however, I have trouble constructing an open rectangle that is a subset of a given open ball that contains the point in question. Any help on how to succinctly do so?

Comment: This boils down to using that norms are equivalent on $\mathbb{R}^n$. How familiar are you with this concept?

Comment: Take the distance $d$ from $x=(x_1,...,x_n)$ to the sphere which is the boundary of the ball. Then the box $\prod_{i=1}^{n}[x_i-d/n,x_i+d/n]$ is inside that sphere. Since $d/n$ is half-the side of this hypercube then, by Pythagoras, half of its diagonal is $\frac{d}{n}\sqrt{n}=\frac{d}{\sqrt{n}}$, which is smaller than $d$.

Comment: The usual definition is that for each $x \in U$, $U$ contains an open ball centered at $x$. You could of course also modify the definition by requiring that for each  $x \in U$, $U$ contains an open ball $B$ such that $x \in B$. Then you have to show that the usual definiton is equivalent to the modified definition. This is fairly easy.

Answer (score 1):

This follows from a standard inequality: for $x=(x_1,...,x_n)\in\mathbb{R^n}$ we have $||x||\leq\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|$ where $||x||$ is the Euclidean norm.

So now suppose $x=(x_1,...,x_n)$ is a point in an open ball $B$. Without loss of generality $x$ is the center of $B$, otherwise just build a smaller ball with center in $x$ which is contained in $B$. Let's say the radius of $B$ is $r$. Then $B=\{y: ||x-y||<r\}$. Now I say the rectangle $(x_1-\frac{r}{n},x_1+\frac{r}{n})\times...\times (x_n-\frac{r}{n},x_n+\frac{r}{n})$ is contained in $B$. Indeed, if $y=(y_1,...,y_n)$ is in that rectangle then:

$||y-x||\leq\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i-y_i|\leq\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{r}{2n}=\frac{r}{2}<r$

Comment: To the proposer: Also observe that the open ball $B'=\{y:\|y-x\|<r/n\}$ is contained in this rectangle because if $y=(r_1,...,y_n)\in B'$ then we cannot have $|x_i-y_i|>r/n$ for some (any)  $i$ else  $\|x-y\|^2\ge |x_i-y_i|^2\ge (r/n)^2.$